# loadrunner widgets - how do they match?

Tags: widget, loadrunner

I am going to loadtest an application that is built using wickets framework and consists of several widgets/small applications within the main application.
Does Loadrunner support this kind of application infrastructure in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with wickets. Generally LoadRunner intercepts network traffic and generate script unless you are using protocols that based on browser like truclient, GUI and etc. If you know what network protocol used in that framework, LoadRunner should work.